# Репутация за комментарии

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, комментарии, репутация

Порой так случается, что на поставленный вопрос ответ дается в виде комментария. Этого бывает даже вполне достаточно для удовлетворения ТС. Более того, комментарий может собрать несколько "плюсов" и подняться вверх по списку комментариев. Однако это никак не влияет на репутацию комментатора. К тому же, если ответ уже получен в виде комментария, другие пользователи (сужу по себе) могут отказаться от написания ответа (именно в форме ответа), т.к. это, имхо, можно считать уже неким плагиатом. В итоге, такой вопрос фактически имеет ответ (проблема решена), но с точки зрения SO ответов нет и комментатор никак не вознагражден.

Возможно (и разумно) ли обеспечить увеличение репутации за полезный комментарий и предусмотреть некий механизм переноса комментария в статус ответа (например ТСом) в пару кликов?

Предполагаю, что такое глобальное изменение может быть реализовано только на уровне всего SO. А если этого до сих пор не сделано, то, видимо, есть разумные на то объяснения. Хотелось бы их послушать.

Comment: автор комментария всегда может добавить ответ. Если он этого не делает значит считает, что комментария достаточно :)

Comment: @Grundy здесь тоже в комментариях будем отвечать? :) На самом деле комментарий может быть выдан именно в виде догадки, а по факту оказаться ответом. Всё равно, я считаю, что не очень правильно, когда фактический статус вопроса не отражает формальный, ну и то, что полезный комментарий не влияет на репутацию.

Comment: Система нацелена на накопление знаний, полезных всем программистам  в виде ответов, а не только конкретной помощи ТС.   Ответ, в отличии от комментария,  подразумевает достаточно полное изложение решения. Поэтому комментарии не приветствуются (в ответе я, по идее, должен был бы разжевать все эти очевидные соображения)

Comment: @avp насчет разжевывания тоже были споры, что лучше - краткий ответ или максимально подробный.

Comment: @avp _"Система нацелена на накопление знаний"_ -- это в теории. на практике просто ставят минус, потому что, цитирую "ответ не понравился" - [тут](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34436/discussion-between-grundy-and-stack)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ответы в комментариях - чистое зло. Причём именно по описанным в вашем вопросе причинам. Этот явление надо искоренять, а не поощерять репутацией.

Если комментатор хотел принести пользу будущим посетителям - ему стоило запостить свой "достаточный" комментарий как ответ. А не ограничиваться ссылкой в комментариях или намёком "копай куда-то". Потому что такой "полезный" комментарий означает, что десяткам/сотням других участников придётся именно копать, а не пользоваться готовым решением, о котором комментатор знал, но предпочёл его не излагать.

SO - база решений. А не каталог ссылок или подсказок.

На сайте существует порог репутации для создания комментариев. Подразумевается, что человек, оставивший комментарий, уже задавал вопросы или отвечал на них, и понимает, что репутации за комментарий он не получит. Т.е. отказ от репутации в этом случае - полностью добровольный

На сайте есть механизм переноса комментариев в ответ - обычным копированием текста. Топикастер (или любой другой участник!) может запостить содержимое чужого комментария как ответ. Это вполне приветствуется. Если при этом опасаетесь обвинений в воровстве репутации - отметьте ответ как общий.

Comment: В дополнение: если ответ на основе комментария или повторяет его, то стоит дать ссылку на этот комментарий.

Comment: _"ему стоило запостить свой "достаточный" комментарий как ответ."_ -- и в итоге придет кто-то, кто не разобрался в вопросе, прочтет ответ, он ему не понравится и [поставит минус](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483506/#comment559488_483513) - продолжение в чате. а так как тут говорят что "важна репутация", то в следующий раз думаешь, - а нужен ли мне еще один комариный укус в ответ на ответ хоть с каким-то решением. или лучше писать к комментах.

Comment: @Stack imho, репутация тут важна только до порога в 3000 (правки сообщений без аппрува), да и минусы на нее не влияют почти. один плюс == 5 минусам.

Comment: _"репутация тут важна только до порога в 3000"_ -- ок. а когда будет (если будет) раздача футболок от ruSO, репутация будет учитываться?

Comment: @Stac0 скорее всего да, но вашей текущей - точно хватит :)

Comment: @PashaPash _"ему стоило запостить свой "достаточный" комментарий как ответ."_ -- как показывает практика, то лучше не надо. вот [пример](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2336/)

Answer (score 6):

Ответ в комментарии - это значит что отвечающий поленился написать полноценный ответ, или ему не важна репутация.

Лень не должна поощряться, так что никакой репы за комментарии.

Comment: а может у него было недостаточно времени в данный момент, а потом забылось, что нужно еще и ответ добавить

Comment: @Grundy, значит ему просто не нужна репа.

Comment: @avp, ага, такое тоже бывает :-)

Comment: _"никакой репы за комментарии"_ -- в таком случае, для баланса, надо отключить минусы. оставить только плюсы за ответ. а то некоторые не разбираются в вопросе. а ответы тупо минусуют, потому что им ответ не понравился. как он мог не понравиться если вопрос не поняли. а если поняли вопрос, то почему ответ не написали, а поставили минус другому ответу.

Comment: @Stack, наоборот, надо сделать минусы для комментариев. А то хочется минусануть Ваш, но никак (

Comment: @Abyx _"надо сделать минусы для комментариев."_ -- и получите информационный пузырь еще быстрее. кого на сайте больше и кто  активнее ставит лайки - правильно, новички. и получается, что те кто специализируется на ответах для них получает большой рейтинг. и он начинает притягивать новые лайки, хотя ответы слабые. в итоге новички смотрят на слабые ответы и получается нехорошо. но это наверное сложно понять. надо какую-нибудь модель построить и показать как это происходит.

Comment: @Abyx _"хочется минусануть Ваш, но никак"_ -- если знаете ответ то напишите его. или как вы сказали "поленился написать", и проще поставить минус :)

Answer (score 4):

> это никак не влияет на репутацию комментатора

но есть «утешительные призы»:

- [знак «комментатор»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/31/commentator) — оставить 10 комментариев
- [знак «учёный муж»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/56/pundit) — оставить 10 комментариев, получивших минимум 5 баллов

> комментарий может собрать несколько "плюсов" и подняться вверх по списку комментариев

насколько я вижу, комментарии **всегда** отображаются в том порядке, в котором их добавляли. даже если часть комментариев скрыта (когда их много и полный список разворачивается после нажатия кнопки «показать все комментарии»).

Comment: А вот у меня есть юзерскрипт, который меняет порядок комментариев. Рекомендую ) https://gist.github.com/NickVolynkin/d0536b5dfca6a6cf529b

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а какой смысл менять порядок?

Comment: строится (по возможности) дерево комментариев, видно кто и кому отвечал. Удобнее выделять диалоги из общего потока.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fnIji.png

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если вы его лично писали, то, может быть, имеет смысл опубликовать его на http://stackapps.com/ ?

Comment: неа, он как раз оттуда взят, но я слегка подточил, чтобы работал на ru.SO. Я не настолько знаю JS, чтобы писать пользовательские скрипты.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а он действительно как-то догадывается, на какой именно комментарий был ответ?

Comment: думаю, по фрагментам  "@username". Чаще угадывает, бывает что ошибается. Вот это сообщение не подобрал в дерево, т.к. нет обращения к вам в начале.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jILUe.png

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, мне лично такой скрипт не нужен, а кому-то может и пригодиться. может быть, опубликуете сделанные вами изменения в качестве ответа под оригинальным скриптом на stackapps?