# Отправка комментария на Enter

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, комментарии

В вопросах и ответах нажатие <kbd>Enter</kbd> приводит к переходу на новую строку, а вот в комментариях это же действие отправляет комментарий. Уже неоднократно из-за этого возникала ситуация незапланированной отправки комментария. Так, что приходилось в спешном порядке его редактировать.

Можно ли как-то запретить отправку комментария по <kbd>Enter</kbd> во избежании таких ситуаций?

Comment: А какое поведение вы ожидаете по кнопке Enter если в комментариях не сохраняются переносы строк?

Comment: @Grundy как вариант, возможность настроить отправку на `Ctrl+Enter` или вывод окошка с подтверждением отправки, т.е. по сути двойное нажатие `Enter`.

Comment: Это еще одна "фича", подталкивающая Вас писать **ответы** (или тренирующая аккуратность).

Comment: Для начала надо поддержку переводов строк выпросить...

Comment: @Qwertiy, тогда точно все будут писать ответы в комментарии :-)

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/2061/disable-enter-for-submitting-comments

Comment: @Qwertiy за переводами строк начнут просить все остальные фичи форматирования ответов. К чему это приведет?

Comment: А за что минусы вопросу? Объясните, кто-нибудь.

Comment: @VladD могу предположить, что за то, что такая идея мало кому нравится. Т.е. это как бы голосование "за" и "против". А ещё это можно назвать борьбой с оппозицией как с врагами народа, ха-ха :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPD: Alexander Barakin [подсказал ссылку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2322/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-enter/2326?noredirect=1#comment6953_2322) на userscript, который отменяет действие Enter в поле ввода комментария: [Disable enter for submitting comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2061/disable-enter-for-submitting-comments).

Установите его и лично для вас поведение сайта поменяется на желаемое.

---

Если в комментарии вам понадобился перенос строки, то с большой вероятностью вы пишете ответ. Его не нужно публиковать как комментарий. Ваш второй вопрос как раз усиливает впечатление, что вы используете комментарии для ответов: [Репутация за комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2320/181472).

> В вопросах и ответах нажатие Enter приводит к переходу на новую строку

Только в поле тела сообщения. В заголовке, метках и комментарии к правке нажатие Enter воспринимается как отправка.

То же самое в быстром редактировании меток, строке поиска, чате, меню тревог и вообще везде на сайте.

Отправка или подтверждение действия по нажатию Enter - стандартное поведение на этом сайте и почти везде в интернете для всех элементов страницы кроме текстового поля. Уверен, что это поведение не стоит менять.

Кстати, это уже обсуждалось на Мете En.SO: [Can we have the ability to hit return in comments without it posting the comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297563/2790048)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34464/discussion-on-answer-by-nick-volynkin----enter).

Answer (score 4):

столкнулся с тем же самым, выяснил следующее:

во время написания или правки комментария при нажатии `Enter` сообщение (комментарий) отправляется а при нажатии `Shift+Enter` происходит переход на новую строку.

Comment: Но в отправленном комментарии этот перевод строки не отображается :)