# Отправка комментариев по Enter срабатывает даже при открытом контекстном меню

Tags: дефект, правки, комментарии

Вопрос [Отправка комментария на Enter](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2322/) видел.
И поскольку он отклонён, опишу другую проблему отдельно.

При написании приходится исправлять орфографию — нажимаешь копку контекстного меню на клавиатуре (справа, между <kbd>Alt</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) и, выбрав правильное слово, нажимаешь <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd>.

[image: Экранный снимок проблемы]

При этом происходит отправка комментария. Что весьма плохо — доставляет неудобство, и вообще в плане юзабили неправильное поведение, приходится хвататься за мышку при наборе текста. Приходить править уже отправленный комментарий. И пока правишь, есть риски, что будет прочитан обрывок.

Мода на отправку по <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd>, о которой упоминалось том топике — плохая мода. Отправка должна приходить по <kbd>Ctrl + ↵ Enter</kbd>. Хотя бы потому, что <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd> — это перевод каретки. Но раз это никто менять не собирается, то хотя бы контекстное меню браузеров пускай не перехватывается.

Это наблюдается в Firefox 49.0.2 под Windows

Comment: *Google Chrome 54.0.2840.99 m для Windows*, не воспроизводится.

Comment: Тогда добавлю - это в Firefox 49.0.2 под Windows

Comment: @SeVlad, добавь это в тело вопроса

Comment: @Grundy, добавил

Comment: Проверяю FF 50.1.0 в Win 7 - воспроизводится.