# Как переносить текст на новую строчку?

Tags: поддержка

пробовал shift+enter, переносят в редакторе, но на входе оно  переносится только с более чем двойным shift+enter:

текст с двойным shift+enter;
текст с одинарным shift+enter;

[image: Такая вот шляпа]

Comment: Шифты не нужны, да и в примере вашем уже есть само решение.

Comment: Где? В упор не вижу

Comment: Шифты нужны. Иначе сообщение просто отправится.

Comment: Короче говоря, добавьте два пробела перед Enter. P.S. На голый Enter сообщение никогда не отправлялось, если конечно у вас фокус не на кнопке отправки стоит.

Comment: Ну, на телефоне то же. Но я не знаю как здесь переходить на новую строку.  Шифта то нет

Comment: В комментариях переноса на новую строку нет. Если вдруг речь об этом. В итоге текст всё равно будет одной строкой и ограничен только шириной блока с автоматическим переносом.

Comment: Ещё один возможный дубликат: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2322

Comment: Для экспериментов с форматированием есть специальный пост на MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/339911

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для перевода текста на новую строку нужно закончить предыдущую двумя пробелами.

Ссылка на страницу справки по форматированию есть в редакторе, открывается через иконку вопросика:

> [image: редактор текста]

Далее — «расширенная справка»

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: А через телефон как это сделать?

Comment: @Miron а что у вас на телефонной клавиатуре нет кнопки пробела? Или экран не сенсорный?

Comment: Да есть. Поставил два пробела и нажал  Enter. Сообщение отправилось

Comment: @Miron где вы вводите эти пробелы? Просто на картинке в вопросе — поле ввода **сообщения**, а судя по описываемому вами поведению, речь о **комментариях**. Это совершенно разные сущности.

Comment: А в комментариях нельзя новую строку брать?

Comment: @Miron [нельзя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2322/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-enter#comment7687_2346)