# Удалять такие ответы или нет?

Tags: обсуждение

Ситуация: есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483634/) о конвертации кодировки.
В комментариях к вопросу было несколько предложений из серии *"Попробуйте так"*. Я написал свое предложение, после этого у @PashaPash♦ я прочел фразу *"[Если комментатор хотел принести пользу будущим посетителям - ему **стоило запостить свой "достаточный" комментарий как ответ**.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2321/196972)"*
Поэтому я оформил свое предложение с работающим кодом на C# как [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483661/196972).
И так получилось, что практически одновременно со мной (т.к. бывают разные задержки в сети и на серверах) автор вопроса опубликовал свое решение. За мой ответ ставят +1.

Через 10 часов читаю следующее: *"мне кажется разумнее всего было бы удалить данный ответ - так как он не является ответом на вопрос – Bald [1 час назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483634/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-sms-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-gsm-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC/483661?noredirect=1#comment559863_483661)".*
Надо заметить, что Bald не является автором вопроса.
После этого сообщения была неконструктивная беседа с Bald, а мой ответ стал набирать минусы.

Понятно, что мое предложение не было ответом. Но я нашел статью, где есть решение вопроса и есть подробное описание и приводится код на C#. Ссылку на статью я добавил в свой ответ.

**Вопрос: надо ли удалить мой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483661/196972) или нет?**

---

**UPDATE 2**

Почему в [похожей ситуации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484170/196972), когда ответ не подходит автору, не ставят минусы и Bald не предлагает "удалить ответ"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPDATE 1**

Обратите внимание на слова Bald'а: *"я просто сам недавно ковырял отправку смс через gsm модем, и прошел через ад под названием PDU формат"* - [тут](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26910518#26910518)
Т.е. он раньше разбирался с вопросом, но не опубликовал решение, **он никак не помог** автору вопроса. А вместо этого **он хочет, чтобы я удалил свой ответ** вместе с дополнениями.
Мне кажется, что это неправильно. Нельзя SO превращать в справочную.
Как я понимаю, SO служит для обмена опытом. Тут можно и нужно дополнять свои ответы.

В правилах SO сказано, что надо дополнять ответ, а не удалять.
Дополнения называются - **[улучшающие правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/691/196972)**.

Comment: @PavelMayorov _"на момент, когда возник конфликт, ответ Stack не содержал ни слова"_ -- конфликт возник после "удали ответ" от Bald'а, когда я как-раз собирался дополнить ответ. считаете что не надо было дополнять? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov а ваши ответы мне тоже минусовать? например [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483136/196972). у автора "задача на нахождение середины отрезка". а вы ему что отвечаете? цитарую: "Вы сейчас думаете не над теми вещами. Выражаясь образно, вы сейчас похожи на человека, которому надо покрасить забор" -- это ответ? :) но вам наверное везет, и вы получили за такое 4 плюса.

Comment: Можете поставить мне минус, у меня там достаточно плюсов :) Да, это совсем не ответ на вопрос - но это совет автору вопроса. И через N дней этот вопрос наверняка удалят - вместе с моим не-ответом на него.

Comment: @PavelMayorov _"Можете поставить мне минус"_ -- для чего? не вижу смысла в минусаторстве.

Comment: Это был ответ на ваш вопрос: "а ваши ответы мне тоже минусовать?"

Comment: Кстати, только что вспомнил. В том вопросе автор вообще-то спросил: *"Как объявить точки отрезка?"* - и именно на этот вопрос я и ответил. Так что у меня там настоящий ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @PavelMayorov _"Кстати, только что вспомнил."_ -- т.е. вы по ссылкам не переходите, вы просто вспоминаете, что было :). это объясняет почему вы написали тут ответ. постарайтесь перейти по [ссылке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483136/196972), там у автора "задача на нахождение середины отрезка".

Comment: Вообще-то я переходил по ссылке. Вопрос, к слову, называется *"c# - способы представления конечных точек отрезка на плоскости для нахождения его середины"* - и именно на него я и отвечал.

Comment: @PavelMayorov _"способы представления конечных точек отрезка на плоскости"_ -- а в тексте сказано, что у автора "задача на нахождение середины отрезка". вы хотите сказать, что ваш ответ с кучей букв как-то помгает? вы сами-то такой страшный код у себя пишете, как советуете? :) только вдумайтесь, вы пишете кучу букв про то как можно определить переменную. я думал такие вопросы надо просто удалять. или пошутить как в [примере @Grundy](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26900465#26900465). хотя если вы специализируетесь на таких ответах, то все ок :)

Answer (score 8):

Решайте сами. В качестве утешения - за удаление вам дадут бедж [Давление Общества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure).

Никто не запрещает вам постить то, что вы считаете ответом.

Никто не запрещает другим пользователям голосовать за или против вашего ответа.

---

Мое мнение, как дотнетчика - ваш ответ проблему, описанную в вопросе, не решает - т.к. вопрос там не столько в конвертации кодировки, сколько в угадывании специфической кодировки, используемой при отправке SMS. Конвертация строки в байты конкретной кодировки, в том смысле, в котором вы ее подразумеваете в ответе, поддерживается самим Serial Port.

Более того, он создает впечатление что строки в .net надо конвертировать из одной кодировки в другую (хотя на самом деле это чаще всего не так). Т.е. ваш ответ - это скорее решение для какой-то другой проблемы ("есть криво прочитанная строка, криво была указана кодировка при чтении, и это уже нельзя исправить!"), которая к тому же могла бы быть решена более правильным / стандартным способом (указать правильную кодировку при чтении, а не конвертировать по факту).

Т.е. фраза "используй  UCS2", даже без кода - вполне являлась бы ответом. А ваш ответ, на мой вгляд, - не является.

Но решать, опять же, вам.

Comment: _"ваш ответ проблему, описанную в вопросе, не решает"_ -- не все ответы бывают сразу на 100%. именно поэтому можно вносить дополнения, что я и сделал. дополнения на SO называются [улучшающие правки](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/196972)

Answer (score 6):

Полностью согласен с основной частью [ответа @PashaPash](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2337/6).

Stack Overflow строится на взаимной безвозмездной помощи участников друг другу. Система голосований предусмотрена для того, чтобы любой участник, достигнувший порога необходимой репутации мог, *проголосовать за или против* сообщения, тем самым продвинув его вверх или вниз в выдаче. В результате, наиболее полезные сообщения, *по мнению сообщества*, будут отображаться выше в выдаче – пришедший из поиска человек увидит их первыми.

Таким образом, система голосования дает возможность сообществу (реальным людям, которые разбираются в теме вопроса) классифицировать и, самое главное, проверить публикуемое содержимое. (Как мне кажется, ни для кого не секрет, что многие переходя на вопрос на Stack Overflow даже не читают ответ, а просто копируют код из верхнего ответа.)

Вся база знаний создается сообществом на добровольных началах. На сайте существуют правила. Их можно разделить на обязательные к выполнению (например, тематика сайта или уважительный стиль изложения) и рекомендуемые (например, автору вопроса рекомендуется голосовать за правильный ответ и отмечать его верным). Правила сообщества, от части, создаются самим сообществом. Мы с вами сами решаем, как общаться, на какие темы и как поступать в тех или иных ситуациях. *Правила не создаются желаниями одного участника*. Если кто-то что-то очень-очень хочет и старается всеми силами найти поддержку в рядах коллег, продвигая свои идеи, это не означает, что все сообщество должно следовать этим идеям, до тех пор пока правило не будет поддержано большинством на Мете.

Уверен, в большинстве своем, настоятельно рекомендуя следовать тем или иным «не принятым» правилам, участники сообщества стремятся улучшить сайт, чтобы мы могли создать еще большую ценность для наших коллег (как минимум, я воспринимаю их именно так).

Отталкиваясь от этих рассуждений, как мне кажется, нет ничего плохого в том, что ваш ответ получил несколько голосов против – это лишь оценка сообщества. Более того, один из оставивших минус коллег дал комментарий, почему по его мнению ответ должен быть внизу выдачи ответов.

*Следовать  рекомендациям сообщества или нет – решать только вам.* Сообщество, в свою очередь, вольно поступать так, как считает правильно и наиболее полезно для общей базы знаний.

В завершение. Stack Overflow – это база постоянно пополняемых и улучшаемых решений. После того, как вы внесли правку в сообщение, участники могут изменить свое мнение и проголосовать повторно.

Answer (score 5):

Была строка. Что-то поделали, получили строку. В .NET строка всегда в UTF16.

Значит, это либо ответ на вопрос: "Неправильно прочитал строку, как сконвертировать?" (или, в более красивом варианте: "При распаковке архива получил имена файлов в символах из cp866, как привести их к нормальному виду?"), либо просто бесполезны, поскольку получается та же строка.

Так что очень похоже, что это действительно не является ответом на вопрос.

Comment: на сайте SO ответы можно редактировать не просто так. вчера я оставил свое предложение с кодом на C#, т.к. оно не подошло, то я сегодня нашел решение и дополнил свой ответ. что тут такого? или все свои ответы, которые кому-то не нравятся, я должен удалять? :)

Comment: @Stack, я прокомментировал правильность приведённого кода. Всё остальное я не комментировал.

Comment: _"В .NET строка всегда в UTF16."_ -- правда? :) у меня System.Text.Encoding.Default.BodyName = "koi8-r"

Comment: @Stack, но строки в памяти не хранятся в default. Они конвертируются в UTF16 при чтении. Все строки в UTF16.

Comment: _"Они конвертируются в UTF16 при чтении."_ -- и как это можно проверить/подтвердить?

Comment: @Stack, http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/11/07/when-is-a-string-not-a-string/

Comment: для чего ссылка на большую статью непонятно кого? вопрос же простой: как на C# подтвердить ваше утверждение о кодировке?

Comment: @Stack, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx: A string is a sequential collection of Unicode characters ... a sequential collection of T:System.Char objects that represent a string.

Comment: @Stack, стоит сначала посмотреть, кто это ;)

Comment: _"a sequential collection of Unicode characters"_ -- Unicode = UTF16?

Comment: @Stack, да. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.char(v=vs.110).aspx: Each 16-bit value ranges from hexadecimal 0x0000 through 0xFFFF and is stored in a T:System.Char structure. The value of a T:System.Char object is its 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value.

Comment: _"стоит сначала посмотреть, кто это ;)"_ -- 2 тыс. лет повторяют не сотвори себе кумира. в статье по ссылке сказано: most of the time, UTF-16 is used. most - это не всегда.

Comment: @Stack, вырываешь из контекса. В твоей цитате говорится про IL-код. Дальше говорится, что в памяти UTF-16, поэтому атрибуты, записанные в IL-коде преобразуются из UTF8 в UTF16, что, при невалидной последовательности символов приводит к изменению строки.

Comment: _"вырываешь из контекса."_ -- я статью полностью не читал. если бы я получил код, который подтверждает ваше утверждение про UTF-16, то мы бы уже поставили точку. но кода нет :( а слова, ссылки на авторитетов - не очень то и нужны. нужен код.

Comment: @Stack, есть спецификация языка. Очень хочется проверить - возьми финт с невалидным UTF8 в атрибуте и повтори. Или в unsafe-блоке поменяй значение какого-то символа в строке и посмотри, что получится.

Comment: _"есть спецификация языка"_ -- слова, опять слова. покажите код, который подтверждает ваше утверждение "В .NET строка всегда в UTF16.". и обратите внимание, что .NEТ - это не язык!

Comment: @Stack, спецификация платформы тоже есть.

Comment: _"спецификация платформы тоже есть"_ -- это никак не подтверждает ваше утверждение "В .NET строка всегда в UTF16.".  если не можете подтвердить, то исправьте свой ответ, чтобы не формировать мифы.

Comment: @Stack, это не миф. А если считаешь, что миф, то опровергни его.

Comment: _"если считаешь, что миф, то опровергни его"_ -- ну здрасте. вы утверждаете "В .NET строка всегда в UTF16.", подтвердить не можете, а я его должен опровергать ваше неаргументированное утверждение?! :) хитрый прием ;)

Comment: @Stack III.1.1.3 Character data type
A CLI char type occupies 2 bytes in memory and represents a Unicode code unit using UTF-16
encoding.  ECMA-335 6-th Edition / June 2012

Comment: _"a Unicode code unit using UTF-16 encoding."_ -- ок. как проверить? какой код запустить, чтобы получить подтверждение?

Comment: @Qwertiy вы как специалист по кодировкам помогите ответить на вопрос [Как прочесть "ЇаЁўҐв"?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483912/)

Answer (score 5):

Привожу тот [вариант ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/483661/1), который висел на сайте 12 часов:

> Конвертировать кодировку можно так
>
> ```
> Encoding src = Encoding.Default;
> Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
> byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(text);
> byte[] srcBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, src, utfBytes);
> string msg = src.GetString(srcBytes);
> ```

Во-первых, здесь предлагается закодировать строку в массив байт, перекодировать массив байт - после чего раскодировать в строку обратно. Этот алгоритм не решает задачу (в правильном алгоритме надо два раза кодировать без декодирования).

Во-вторых, тут нет ни упоминания кодировки UCS2, ни упоминания шестнадцатиричного кодирования байтов.

Лично мне кажется, что этот ответ не имеет **ничего общего** с правильным ответом. Его не надо "дорабатывать", его надо переписать заново. Уже тогда его следовало удалить, на что и намекают полученные минусы.

Правильный ответ, данный Little Fox, был дан примерно в то же время.

Потом прошло 12 часов - и вы решили "исправить" свой ответ, дописав в него все то, что сочинил другой участник - и теперь заявляете, что "дали свой ответ раньше". Дали-то раньше - но совсем не тот.

Как мне кажется, такое поведение - это нарушение лицензии CC BY-SA 3.0, используемой на SO.

Comment: _"Во-первых, здесь предлагается закодировать"_ -- разложили все по полочкам как эксперт :) а [на SO за этот код 71 плюс](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1922253/5673266)

Comment: @Stack что-то я не вижу там ни слова про SMS в вопросе. Я же не говорю, что код плохой - он попросту не решает задачу.

Comment: _"вариант ответа, который висел на сайте 12 часов:"_ -- и что? я предложил в комментах этот вариант. после этого прочел пост модератора, что надо публкиовать предложения не в комментах, а как  ответ. что я и сделал. пошел спать. утром собрался дополнить  ответ. что я и сделал после того как обсудил с Bald его "удали ответ". а вы где были? как помогли автору? думаете ему нужен ваш минус к моему ответу? :)

Comment: _"Правильный ответ, данный Little Fox, был дан примерно в то же время"_ -- так и есть. я нажал отправить и закрыл вкладку. код который приводится в ответе скопипастили с хабра. я нашел статью, дал на нее ссылку и улучшил код. а вам это не нравится, да? :)

Comment: _"теперь заявляете, что "дали свой ответ раньше""_ -- что за бред?! проблема в том, что мне сказали "удали ответ", когда я собирался его дополнить. вы это понимаете или нет? _"Как мне кажется, такое поведение"_ -- что вам еще кажется? :)

Comment: Так дополнили бы! Нет, сначала 12 часов ругались в комментариях и чате, а потом спохватились.

Comment: _"сначала 12 часов срались в комментариях и чате"_ -- вижу вам совсем плохо. вы бы хоть на время смотрели и [на ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483661/196972)

Comment: Дискуссия ходит по кругу. Я уже отвечал про время.

Comment: _"Дискуссия ходит по кругу"_ -- нет дискуссии. есть раздраженные минусаторы. которые выссказывают свое возмущение. пишут кучу букв, проводят расследования. обвиняют. вместо того чтобы посмотреть правила SO про улучшающие правки и посмотреть на сам [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483661/196972), который минусаторы так энергично обсуждают :)

Comment: Нет правила, запрещающего минусовать. Есть только один участник, который никак не поймет, почему его ответы никто не хочет улучшать.

Comment: _"Есть только один участник, который никак не поймет, почему его ответы никто не хочет улучшать"_ -- вы о чем? вы [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483661/196972) видели? что не так? а свои сказки, про то что было или что вы там что-то подумали - оставьте при себе.

Comment: вы так хорошо разложили по полочкам про кодировки, помогите ответить на вопрос [Как прочесть "ЇаЁўҐв"?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483912/) а то все про [способы определения переменных](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483136/196972) отвечаете, проявите свои знания на более сложном вопросе.

Comment: Не буду я ничего делать "на слабо", я уже вырос.

Comment: Правка своего ответа никакие лицензии не нарушает. Добавление в ответ кода другого ответа тоже никакие лицензии не нарушает — у нас тут _очень_ много переводных ответов, и далеко не все они ставят ссылку на оригинал.

Comment: @PavelMayorov тут [похожая ситуация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484170/196972). почему нет вашего минуса? почему нет вашего расслеования по этому поводу? :)

Comment: @Stack причин три: во-первых, я этого ответа не видел. Во-вторых, там другая ситуация. В-третьих, мне так захотелось.

Comment: @PavelMayorov _" там другая ситуация."_ -- другая потому что timestamp другой? :) _"мне так захотелось"_ -- а тут вам не хочется из-за ромбика, понимаю. _"я этого ответа не видел"_ -- да, ромбик - это как плащ-невидимка для ответов. вы их не видите.

Answer (score 5):

Давайте посмотрим на временную шкалу сообщения. Все даты буду публиковать как они мне показываются, то есть в своём часовом поясе. Даты могут быть иными, чем у читателя, но порядок не нарушится.

- 2016-01-17 19:13:36Z опубликован ответ Little Fox
- 2016-01-17 19:15:30Z опубликован ответ Stack
- 2016-01-17 19:18:13Z комментарий от **Little Fox**: *«и так пытался, не работало. Уже добавил ответ. Оказалось нужна UCS2»*.
- (прошло примерно 10 часов)
- 2016-01-18 05:04:52Z комментарий от **Bald**: *«мне кажется разумнее всего было бы удалить данный ответ - так как он не является ответом на вопрос»*
- 2016-01-18 05:45:52Z ответный комментарий от **Stack**: *«...в вопросе сказано "Кодировка кириллицы для отправки". в общем случае используется Encoding.Convert. и возможно, что именно этот способ поможет кому-то в дальнейшем.»*
- 2016-01-18 05:52:49Z один из трех комментариев получает отметку «неконструктивный». Вскоре модератор отклоняет эту тревогу.
- 2016-01-18 05:53:59Z снова комментарий от **Bald**: *«Вы забыли про для отправки SMS: при отправке смс там своя кодировка: UCS2 для не ASCII, а для формирования длинных смс там еще используется и упаковка 7bit для ASCII сообщений длиннее 140 символов. так что это все таки не ответ на поставленный вопрос»*
- (прошло ещё примерно 2 часа, продолжился спор в комментариях и [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34463/discussion-between-bald-and-stack))
- 2016-01-18 07:49:05Z первая правка ответа.

Какие выводы можно сделать:

- Вы действительно опубликовали ответы почти одновременно с автором вопроса. Конечно, задержка сервера не может внести разницу в 2 минуты — нормальный отклик составляет меньше секунды. Но часто бывает, что кто-то пишет ответ и не видит другие публикуемые ответы. Это нормальная ситуация.
- Через 2 минуты 43 секунды после публикации автор вопроса ответил вам, что он уже пробовал ваше решение и оно не подходит. Из всех обсуждений в принципе понятно почему — для отправки SMS нужна особая кодировка, которая отсутствует в вашем решении.
- После этого становится довольно очевидным, что ваш ответ не подходит для решения этой задачи. Он тем не менее является ответом и ничем иным, и участники дважды подтвердили это в очереди проверок. Но полезность его для решения данной задачи — низкая. Отсюда и минусы. Комментарий Bald был вполне обоснован.

Что можно хорошего сделать в данной ситуации? Можно просто удалить ответ и не собирать минусы (голоса против). Можно сформулировать подходящий хороший вопрос и дать на него ответ — жалко, когда пропадает труд. Можно и отредактировать ответ. Обычно это уместно, когда исправляется ошибка в коде или добавляются подробности. В данном случае требовалась полная переработка ответа, так что я бы порекомендовал вам удалить старый и опубликовать новый, отвечающий на поставленный вопрос. Так он не унаследовал бы минусы от старого ответа.

Что можно неудачного сделать? Воспринять минусы как проявление личной неприязни.

Поверьте, никакого ополчения участников лично против вас **нет**. Есть ополчение за качественные вопросы и ответы, против оффтопика, за спасение некачественных новичковых вопросов и т.п. Участники стараются поддерживать внутренний порядок на сайте в том числе тем, что не поощряют ответы, которые слабо относятся к вопросу. Если их не минусовать, то на любой вопрос начнут отвечать «смотрите, как похожую задачу можно решить в jQuery!»

**Минусы относятся к ответу, а не к вам. Пожалуйста, воспринимайте их именно так.**

Ссылка по теме: [В чем значение голосов «за» и «против»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1036/181472)

Comment: _"комментарий от Bald: «мне кажется разумнее всего было бы удалить данный ответ - так как он не является ответом на вопрос»"_ --   а как он понял, что мой ответ не является ответом? если не знал, то для чего его пост? получает он знал ответ. почему не опубликовал его? кстати, он сказал, что [знал ответ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26910518#26910518) и вместо того чтобы его опубликовать и помочь автору, он пишет замечания. где в правилах на ruSO сказано, что есть ограничение по времени для внесения улучшающих правок? или это негласное правило?

Comment: "Минусы относятся к ответу, а не к вам. Пожалуйста, воспринимайте их именно так" - золотые слова, их бы отлить в граните и вручить всем минусаторам и их жертвам.

Comment: @Stack вполне жизненная ситуация, есть вопрос и неоптимальное решение. Постим вопрос, в надежде получить оптимальное решение, если ответа нет - постим свое неоптимальное решение, которое или поддержат или раскритикуют. Это все отлично вписывается в формат SO. Не забывайте, SO это база вопросов и ответов полезных автору и многим другим людям, а не просто форум помощи авторам.

Comment: @KromStern _"Минусы относятся к ответу, а не к вам"_ -- тут проблема не в минусах, а в "удали ответ". я уже сто раз повторял, что проблема в том, что Bald сказал мне "удали ответ". вы бы удалили ответ, который вы собираетесь дополнить? что я в итоге и сделал [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483661/196972). а слова Bald'а и его "давай выйдем в чат" только отсрочили мою улучшающую правку.

Comment: @Stack Такой ответ я бы удалил, а через 10 часов запостил новый. В вашем случае дополнение было радикально новым ответом.

Comment: @KromStern _"вполне жизненная ситуация, есть вопрос и неоптимальное решение."_ -- да, есть вопрос и предложение "попробуй так", которое по просьбе модератора было оформлено в виде ответа, и я собирался внести улучшающую правку. но тут пришел Bald со своим "удали ответ" и понеслось.

Comment: @Stack Проблема уже изложена и разжевана. Советую вам "зафиксировать убытки" и продолжать жить дальше.

Comment: @KromStern _"Такой ответ я бы удалил, а через 10 часов запостил новый"_ -- посмотрите на даты/время. я запостил ответ и занялся другими делами. то, что ответ не подходит я узнал через 10 часов. а по-вашему мне надо было опубликовать ответ и сразу удалить? :)

Comment: @KromStern _"Советую вам "зафиксировать убытки""_ -- нет никаких убытков. Bald убрал свое сообщение со словами "удали ответ". все минусы, которые мне понаставили, компенсированы в самом [ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483661/196972). я отстоял свою позицию и собираюсь это делать и дальше, в таких ситуациях, но надеюсь, что такое не повторится.

Comment: @Stack а что вы хотите, чтобы неправильные ответы не минусовались пока человек не отметится галкой что "закончил заниматься другими делами" и к минусам готов?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34527/discussion-between-krom-stern-and-stack).

Comment: @KromStern _"а что вы хотите, чтобы неправильные ответы не минусовались"_ -- опять 25 :) тут проблема не в минусах, а **проблема в "удали ответ", сказанная Bald'ом**. я уже сто раз повторял. и [вам тоже говорил](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2336/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82/2351#comment7101_2351)

Comment: @KromStern: спасибо за хорошую оценку. Может, знак введём такой ))

Comment: @KromStern может про *Золотые слова* :)