# Пока готовишь улучшающую правку, надо ли удалять свой ответ?

Tags: обсуждение

Если дал ответ и готовишь [улучшающую правку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/691/196972), надо ли удалять свой ответ?
И есть ли какое-то ограничение по времени, в течение которого надо внести улучшающую правку?
Может надо в ответе ставить отметку о том, что готовится улучшение?

Ситуация:

Публикую ответ. Ухожу спать/отдыхать/... Часов через 10-ть в понедельник с утра вижу, что ответ не подходит. Собираюсь дополнить ответ. Надо ли удалить ответ, пока готовлю улучшение?

Как мне говорят: *"Окружающие не могут залезть к вам в голову и узнать, что вы готовите улучшающую правку."*

Поэтому **предлагаю** добавить отметку в ответы: **готовлю улучшающую правку**.

Это позволит избежать ненужные дискуссии, которые могут возникнуть, когда под ответом, для которого готовится улучшающая правка, кто-то пишет *"удалите данный ответ - так как он не является ответом на вопрос"* -- [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2336).

А если будет отметка "готовлю улучшающую правку", то такая фраза не появится, и не придется тратить время как на замечания, так и на объяснения.

Comment: Встречал несколько ответов более чем годовой давности, в которых авторы либо говорили, что распишут ответ через некоторое время подробнее, либо ещё каким-то образом обозначали свои намерения по расширению ответа, но расширения в итоге не происходило. Такие ответы только создают видимость наличия решения.

Answer (score 9):

Окружающие не могут залезть к вам в голову и узнать, что вы готовите улучшающую правку.

Если вы сразу знаете, что ответ еще недооформлен - можно удалить его, чтобы не ловить минусы и не устраивать ненужные дискуссии. Хотя по-хорошему, если вы действительно не готовы полностью ответить стоит подождать, когда у вас будет время на полный ответ. В противном случае выглядит так, словно вы застолбили место своим ответом.

Comment: _"если вы действительно не готовы полностью ответить стоит подождать"_ -- нет черно/белых ситуаций. есть вопросы, в которых нет всего что требуется. это обычная ситуация с заказчиками. в качестве примера посмотрите комментарии под [ответом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484065/196972) -- пришлось вносить ряд улучшающих правок. считате, что надо было удалить ответ  сразу, после первого уточнения? и обсуждать в комментах под вопросом. но это было бы как-то странно, если комменты автора удалятся с удаленным ответом. не так ли?

Comment: вот свежий пример: PashaPash пишет ответ. а автор вопроса [пишет "не помогло...."](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483993/#comment560780_484170). PashaPash должен удалить ответ? :)

Comment: @Stack: Мне кажется, минусы зависят не от того, понравился ли ответ _автору вопроса_, а от того, понравился ли он _сообществу_.

Comment: @VladD когда ставят минус надо писать за что он. если минусатор знает ответ лучше, то почему не напишет свой ответ? а если не знает ответ, то за что минус? расположение букв не нравится или что? :) а вообще проблема не в минусах, а в том, что пока готовится улучшаюшая правка, кто-то приходит и пишет "удали ответ" и еще пытается качать права. бред же это.

Comment: @Stack: Формально минусатор не должен комментировать минус, но мне всегда молчаливое минусование казалось невежливым и вообще неправильным (т. к. не объясняет, что же не так с т. зр. минусующего).

Comment: _"В противном случае выглядит так, словно вы застолбили место своим ответом"_ - эм.. либо ты слишком кратко выражаешь мысль, либо я не понимаю, а что в этом плохого?

Comment: @Qwertiy, вы не сталкивались с конфликтами "Я первый написал этот ответ"?

Comment: Да как-то не сталкивался. На сложные вопросы сложно написать одинаковые ответы, а на простые как-то странно бросать незаконченный ответ из одного предложения.

Comment: @Nofate _"вы не сталкивались с конфликтами "Я первый написал этот ответ"? "_ -- нет. зато нередко бывает нарушения правил SO, но почему-то никто [на такое](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/410621/) не обращает внимание. а один из моих ответов после сообшения модератора пришлось удалить, т.к. там было небольшое описание и ссылка на enSO с кодом и решением.

Answer (score 5):

Если ответ оказался ошибочным, или просто недоделанным, то да.
Если готовится просто дополнение для раскрытия деталей, то нет.

[Примером](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/480803/revisions) является мой ответ 
на твой же вопрос (кстати, ты там до сих пор ничего не сказал).

Отмечу, что при изменениях ответа надо самостоятельно уведомить об этом автора. Собственно, минусовавших тоже, если они известны.

Comment: _"Если готовится просто дополнение для раскрытия деталей, то нет."_ -- согласен. и когда собираешься внести дополнение, а тебе говорят "удали ответ" и "давай выйдем", то наверное у многих в понедельник с утра будет негативная реакция.

Comment: _"Примером является мой ответ на твой же вопрос (кстати, ты там до сих пор ничего не сказал)"_ -- не забыл. просто приоритеты изменились. надо другие дела сделать. но вопрос в силе. я к нему вернусь. т.к. мне надо будет собрать сканы документов в базу. а для этого их надо открывать в браузере и поворачивать вокруг оси в пределах контейнера. приписывать теги и т.д.