# Удаление вопроса о настройке интернета на регистраторе видеонаблюдения 2

Tags: поддержка, модерация, восстановление-сообщений

как раз ХОЧУ ОБСУЖДАТЬ...

для начала:

1. [Как узнать размер файла на диске](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468614/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5/468629#468629)
   тут удален комментарий между

   **@alexander barakin а как же touch, dd, echo, cat? и стоит рассказать (хоть немного) о разных файловых системах, о цилиндрах и блоках (список можно продолжать). – айтишник 13 янв в 21:37**

   и

   **@alexander barakin о чем я и говорю... простая просьба: не смотрите на все только со своей точки зрения, прислушивайтесь и к остальным – айтишник 13 янв в 21:58**
   (не вижу кто удалил комментарий но очень похоже на удаление топика https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484027/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-dvr-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD)
2. @alexander barakin, @Nick Volynkin больше разработчики нежели системные администраторы
3. @alexander barakin может минусовать ответы (например: ) хотя например тут
   [Ubuntu перейти в папку с названием на русском языке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451145/ubuntu-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5/451154#451154) 
   ответ @alexander barakin
   менее информативен чем ответ @Sergey Rufanov (экранирование символов. похоже с пунктом 1. сего сообщения)
   т.е., если начать продолжать поиск, помечать тревогой все такие оплошности это даст какой-то результат?
4. по данной ссылке 
   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators 
   @Nicolas Chabanovsky отсутствует.
5. скажите как мне удалить свой аккаунт полностью или удалите сами т.к. адеквата и углубдения в суть тут не дождешься (оба варианта подразумевают очистку личных и служебных данных).

Comment: Кроме пункта №5, в чем состоит вышенаписанный  вопрос? Какой ответ вы ожидаете получить? Если только №5, то стоит убрать преамбулу.

Comment: если не будет развернутого ответа на первые 4 пункта то остается 5-й. хронология в вопросах указана.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что в пунктах 1-4 вы не задали ни 1 вопроса, а просто привели ряд утверждений?

Answer (score 13):

1. Участник @alexander barakin удалил свой комментарий, вы тоже так можете. Почему он это сделал, знает только он.
2. Ок. Это плохо или хорошо? У нас тут все участники равны.
3. Может. А может и плюсовать. И вы можете. И все остальные тоже. Вообще, не зацикливайтесь на минусах и очках репутации. Процитирую @Nick Volynkin♦ из [соседнего обсуждения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2351/1984): *«Минусы относятся к ответу, а не к вам. Пожалуйста, воспринимайте их именно так.»*
4. Да, т.к. он community manager, а не избираемый модератор. Он есть тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile и в списке сотрудников  SO: http://stackexchange.com/about/team
5. Через [форму обратной связи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: 1. если верны правила сообщества то где причины?
2. очень много вопросов разработчиков ничего не смысллящих в системном администрировании.
3. если бы я мог минусовать я бы указывал причину.
4. почему его тут
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators
нет? разве он не модератор? и ромбик присутсвует...

Comment: Он администратор сообщества и штатный сотрудник StackOverflow. И обладает большим спектром прав, чем модератор. На указанной странице показаны только избираемые модераторы.

Comment: @айтишник, Вам же только что написали, в этом списке **только избираемые** (т.е. прошедшие выборы) модераторы, а он часть администрации сайта.

Answer (score 6):

1. Да, там есть комментарий, его удалил сам автор. Модераторы там ничего не трогали.
2. Не понимаю, какое отношение к делу имеют наши специализации и мера профессионализма. Stack Overflow для того и есть, чтобы более опытные участники делились опытом с менее опытными.
3. Минусовать вопросы и ответы могут все участники, имеющие 125 и более репуатции, включая вас.
4. Да, отсутствует, потому что он не избранный сообществом модератор, а менеджер сообщества, сотрудник компании Stack Overflow. А в этом списке только избранные модераторы.
5. Читайте раздел справки [«Как удалить свою учетную запись?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account).

Кстати, вы можете отвечать мне в комментариях к этому ответу, необязательно вопрос задавать. Пожалуйста, задавайте новые вопросы об этой ситуации именно так. А то у нас получаются вопросы и ответы сразу обо всём.

Comment: благодарю. пожалуй, самая лучшая инструкция в сообществе. желаете жалеть - жалейте животных

Comment: @айтишник: не понял. Причём тут жалость?

Comment: по первому пункту: а вам видно содержимое удалённых комментариев? если нет, то текст там был (надеюсь, память не подводит): «да, это моя серьёзная недоработка». подразумевался сарказм. удалён мною после прочтения адресатом, чтобы не засорять сайт оффтопиком.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, содержание видно. Но отображение удаленных включается отдельной кнопкой каждый раз.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account
не работает, пишет
**Данная операция не может быть выполнена на сайте мета; пожалуйста, перейдите на основной сайт**.

Comment: @айтишник: вот эта ссылка должна работать: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact