# Нужно ли удалять комментарии с точной поисковой фразой и отсылкой в гугл?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, комментарии

В этой теме: [Калькулятор на c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811725/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c) - я сделал комментарий наподобие (дословно не помню): "Погуглите метод рекурсивного спуска". Он был удалён с формулировкой

> Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики

Я полностью согласен, что просто посылать в гугл не стоит. Но ведь я привёл **точную** поисковую фразу, по которой находятся **точные** решения.

В этой теме дважды посылают в Википедию (в первом комментарии и ответе). Чем они лучше, что их не удалили? При том, что те ссылки не дают *полного* решения вопроса.

Большинство комментариев под вопросов - вода. Они не дают ничего. Упоминание AST - здорово, но как его построить? Намёк: метод рекурсивного спуска.

Комментарий tym32167 со ссылками на его код - это отличный ответ на вопрос. Но ведь это тоже посыл на сторонний ресурс. А главное - это не даёт понимания ключевой технологии, используемой для парсинга выражений, чтобы можно было дополнительно *погуглить*, если что-то непонятно.

Вы можете сказать: почему бы не написать ответ (скопипастить) из поиска по указанной фразе? Да потому что он громоздкий, не формат для ruSO. Хотя, если кто-то желает, может это сделать (упс, без поисковой фразы желающий не найдёт, откуда и что копипастить).

Заключение: я посылал и буду посылать вопрошающих в поисковики с **точной** поисковой фразой. Вы можете оставить за собой право удалять такие мои комментарии, я оставляю за собой право их делать.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Достаточно часто проблема в новой предметной области не только в том, что не знаешь как что-то сделать, но и в том, что не знаешь как это правильно ищется, называется, ключевые слова, название метода. Зная их - решение найти гораздо проще!

Comment: Если в гугле находятся ответы на ruSO - нужно указывать его как дубликат, а если нет, может быть стоит оформить ответ в виде ответа?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: @Kromster перед поддержкой  - попробуйте погуглить и посмотреть, насколько **легко** там находятся **точные** решения по конкретной фразе из вопроса. С поправкой на уровень задавшего вопрос :). А еще стоит явно разделить "предоставить ключевые слова" и "посоветовать гуглить **вместо того**, чтобы спрашивать". Понятно что вы, и топикастер, за первое. Но пользоваться "результатом голосования" будут, к сожалению, любители второго.

Comment: @PashaPash тем не менее, подобный комментарий несет пользу, и удалять его не надо. (возможно лишь стоит убрать часть про гугл, как не be nice)

Comment: @Kromster я бы убрал, но не считаю допустимым перефразировать чужие комментарии. Т.е. удалить часть комментария - ок. Но заменять слова на другие, бинайсные, я считаю неправильным. И [судя по реакции сообщества - не только я.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7142/177221). А в этом конкретном случае модератору пришлось бы заменять слова. Наверное, он предпочел удалить.

Comment: @PashaPash вот это вот странная политика - удалять полезную информацию из-за мелкого вкрапления "неполезной". Тем более что в вопросах и ответах правки поощряются.

Comment: @Kromster в этом конкретном случае - там скорее было мелкое вкрапление полезной в длинном комментарии. Полный текст "Примеров калькуляторов на многих языках в сети огромное количество. Гуглите, в частности, "метод рекурсивного спуска". Да, в вопросах и ответах правки поощряются. Но только до тех пор, пока слова не начинают заменять другими, "более нейтральными". Посмотрите по ссылке выше, насколько народ злит замена даже одного слова.

Comment: @Kromster я не утверждаю, что этот конкретный коммент точно стоило снести. Но посыл в гугл в нем был. И я не совсем понял смысл первой части. Да, в сети огромное множество всего. Это не значит, что не стоит задавать вопросы на SO :)

Answer (score 8):

### Посылаете в поиск - делайте это с прямой ссылкой на хороший результат.

---

Между отправкой в гугл по *правильной* поисковой фразе и "ссылкой на сторонний ресурс" есть достаточно ощутимая (для новичков!) разница.

Ключевая фраза важна. Подсказать новичку ключевую фразу - это добро. Но это только начало пути к результату.

Гугл дает кучу решений на выбор, без градации лучше / хуже, правильно / не правильно. По "метод рекурсивного спуска C#" гугл дает кучу ссылок на форумы. Из TOP 10 там полезного, готового к использованию - 1-2 (статья на хабре, может быть еще вики). Остальное - *мусор*.

Да, вы, как опытный разработчик, легко можете выбрать и отсеять правильный результат. Новички, к сожалению, не могут. Т.е. вы воспринимаете свой посыл как путь к:

- Прислушался, погуглил по "метод рекурсивного спуска C#"
- Быстрый скан результатов, *пару минут*: cyberforum - нет, wiki-нет, programmersforum-нет, qaru.site, ворующий контент с ruSO - нет, ... вырванные в онлайн куски Шилдта - нет, статья на хабре - ок
- Проводит с пользой время читая развернутую статью с примерами

Ну да, примерно так выглядит гугление в вашем исполнении. Или в моем :)

Но когда это делает новичок, все выглядит по-другому:

- Прислушался, погуглил по "метод рекурсивного спуска C#"
- Ох сколько всего
- cyberforum - вроде код есть, надо вчитываться. Покопипастил, не, не работает и ничего не понятно
- wiki- как умно расписано. идем дальше.
- programmersforum - ответа нет, но хоть раздел называются "помощь студентам". задам там вопрос, вдруг помогут и не посоветуют гуглить.
- qaru.site - о, какой крутой сайт. как SO, только дизайн лучше
- куски Шилдта - теряем пару часов, читаем, не справляемся с отсутствием форматированием у выкинутого в онлайн кода
- пришел назад на ruSO, за одну ссылку до статьи на хабр. хм. идем дальше
- о, статья на хабре. на хабре хорошо расписано. на хабре профессионалы, не то, что на ruSO, *даже ссылки нормальной дать не могут*.

И по такой цепочке вы отправляете всех новичков, которые придут в ваш вопрос. Это вариант "новичку повезло". Гугл, к сожалению, персонализирует результаты. Там где у вас хорошие технические ресурсы - другой может получить сплошное mail.ru. Или того хуже - там сплошной SO - я как-то раз, из интереса, погуглил из коммента "вторая ссылка в гугле по ZZZ" - первые 5 ссылок вели на ruSO без решений.

Посылаете в поиск - делайте это с прямой ссылкой на хороший результат. Формулировка вида

> Вам стоит почитать про метод рекурсивного спуска, вот хорошая статья

в разы эффективнее и полезнее просто "ключевой фразы". И к тому же, не так сильно зависит от персонализации результатов.

Comment: "Ключевая фраза важна. Подсказать новичку ключевую фразу - это добро. Но это только начало пути к результату." Если это добро, почему комментарий был удален? Это ведь был не ответ, а комментарий.

Comment: @FoggyFinder дописал "только" :)

Comment: @FoggyFinder удалял не я, стоит подождать ответа от удалившего. я просто пытаюсь в правильное русло завернуть добро, а не свести его к протесту "запрещают посылать, а я буду, удаляйте сколько хотите".

Comment: @FoggyFinder у меня нет сомнений насчет добрый намерений как топикастера, так и тех, кто его поддерживает. я просто хочу, чтобы это добро было наиболее эффективным.

Comment: я понимаю, но новичка нужно подталкивать к решению, чтобы он что-то делал самостоятельно. Порой подобный комментарий намного более важен, чем полноценный ответ. Хотя я согласен, что свои намерения лучше раскрывать более явно

Comment: @FoggyFinder вы исходите из предположения, что новичок не хотел гуглить, а просто взял и задал вопрос. Задать вопрос на SO вообще-то сложнее, чем погуглить. Если новичок вменяемый - ему достаточно просто дать ключевые слова. Посылать при этом в гугл - не обязательно. Т.е. да, подталкивать надо - но, прежде всего, ключевыми словами, а не посылом в гугл. Сам посыл - это не подталкивание. Это просто посыл.

Comment: @FoggyFinder на всякий случай - комментария топикастера это не касается, он был скорее нейтральным, а не прямо посылающим.

Comment: Считаете ли вы, что в данном контексте перефраз посыла гуглить в фразу вида "посмотрите в сторону %название_решения%" является улучшением? На мой взгляд это полные синонимы и любой человек не знающий об этом решении забьет %название_решения% в поисковик. Также прямая ссылка на хорошее решение является, как я понимаю, плохой практикой по мнению администрации ибо потенциально уводит пользователя на другой ресурс. Единственное правильное решение - писать ответ?

Comment: @yolosora перефраз уберет явный посыл и снизит шанс что кто-то снесет его просто за слово "гугл". Прямая ссылка на решение является вполне нормальной практикой, особенно в случае, если вопрос слишком обширен (как в примере топикастера). Но любой, даже краткий ответ - *гораздо* лучше. Дело не у уводе с ресурса, дело во времени на поиск ответа и в долговечности ссылки. Например, ссылки на msdn magazine сейчас мертвы, и я уже несколько раз оказывался в ситуации, когда мне пришлось копать вебархив в поисках хотя бы года и месяца издания. Последний раз - вчера :(

Answer (score 5):

Поддержу ТС. Комментарий *"Погуглите метод рекурсивного спуска"* - это вполне корректная фраза. Да, она не является ответом - но как комментарий она вполне допустима. Кажется, тут периодически новички ноют что <s>карму</s> рейтинг негде набирать? Между прочим, отличная возможность для них погуглить, написать ответ и получить заслуженные плюсы.

К сожалению, недавно некоторые слова стали в комментариях запретными, и "погуглите" - одно из них. Предлагаю в таких случаях пользоваться синонимами. Я бы мог написать этот комментарий как-нибудь вот так:

1. Попробуйте поискать по ключевым словам "рекурсивный спуск" - кажется, это именно то что вам нужно.
2. Ключевые слова - "рекурсивный спуск", попробуйте поискать по ним.
3. Кажется, вам нужен метод рекурсивного спуска.

Comment: Сильно по касательной проходит тема "ответы в ответы", когда возможность дописать ответ оставляют любому желающему ([раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4671/213987), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419/213987)). Но всё-таки "[SO - база решений, а не каталог ссылок или подсказок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2321/213987)"

Comment: @AK но если запрещать "комментарии-подсказки" - то больше ответов не станет, вот в чем проблема.

Comment: @AK не увидел в этих ответах ни одной причины, почему такие комментарии могут нести вред. А вот отсутствие комментария может быть причиной того, что не появится хороший ответ.

Comment: Ух ты, вот и начнём обходить вордфильтры, как в старые времена первых форумов.

Answer (score 3):

Что хорошо:

- комментарий, подсказывающий конкретный *специфичный* для задачи путь к решению.
  Плюсом является ссылка на хороший по вашему мнению источник.

Что ещё лучше:

- ответ, показывающий [даже кратко] решение.
  Если слишком мало информации в ответе к дополнению к ссылке (то есть, если ответ содержит ссылку на решение, вместо самого решения), то его могут просто в комментарий преобразовать.

Что плохо:

- посыл в гугл, не упоминая новой информации. К примеру, [посыл в гугл с заголовком вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/23044).

Комментарий *«Погуглите метод рекурсивного спуска»* можно заменить на синонимичную фразу *«Посмотрите в сторону метода рекурсивного спуска»*, где слова "рекурсивного спуска" являются ссылкой на хороший по вашему мнению источник. Если вам тяжело найти ссылку, зная ответ, то спрашивающему (и другим людям с похожей проблемой), может быть ещё тяжелее . См. пример в [ответе @PashaPash](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7218/23044).

> [A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Consistency)

С другой стороны, наличие полезных ключевых слов уже половиной решения может быть, поэтому возможно просто по невнимательности на автомате ваш комментарий удалили. То есть не стоит правилам чисто формально механически следовать, если вы уверены, что ваше действие улучшает сайт, способствует [миссии сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044).